# SQL insert multiple rows depending on number of rows returned from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 SQL tables **Companies**, **Materials** and **Suppliers** as follows.
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHe3q.png)

I need to insert values into **Suppliers** from a list which contains Company Name and Material Name as headers. However, I have multiple companies with the same name in the database and i need to add a new value into **suppliers** for each one of those companies.

For e.g. my list containes values ['Wickes','Bricks'] . I have this sql below to add a new entry into the **suppliers** table but since i have multple companies called 'Wickes' I'll get an error as the subquery will return more than 1 value.

```
INSERT INTO Suppliers(Id,CompanyId,MaterialId) VALUES (NEWID(), (SELECT Id FROM Companies WHERE Name = 'Wickes'),(SELECT Id FROM Materials WHERE Name = 'Bricks'))
```

Whats the best solution to get the Id of all the companies there are called 'Wickes' and then add vales into the suppliers table with that Id and the relevant material Id of 'Bricks'.

Comment: _I have multiple companies with the same name in the database_ Then fix that first. You should be enforcing all natural keys in a table. Why would you allow multiple rows with the same name? That concept applies to all tables.

Comment: And why would you define Suppliers.MaterialId as varchar when the "real" column is int. And varchar(WHAT)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSERT () SELECT..` rather than `INSERT () VALUES()`, e.g

```
INSERT INTO Suppliers (Id, CompanyId, MaterialId) 
SELECT  NEWID(), c.Id, m.Id
FROM    Companies AS c
        CROSS JOIN Materials AS m
WHERE   c.Name = 'Wickes'
AND     m.Name = 'Bricks';
```

This will ensure that if you have multiple companies/materials with the same name, all permutations are inserted. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=451b932a0478d6b8fb287c47753d89d6)

Although based on your image `Suppliers.Id` is an integer, so I think [`NEWID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is not doing what you think it is here, you probably just want:

```
INSERT INTO Suppliers (CompanyId, MaterialId) 
SELECT  c.Id, m.Id
FROM    Companies AS c
        CROSS JOIN Materials AS m
WHERE   c.Name = 'Wickes'
AND     m.Name = 'Bricks';
```

And let [`IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) take care of the `Id` column in `Suppliers`.

As a further aside, I've also just noted that `MaterialId` is `VARCHAR` in your `Suppliers` table, that looks like an error if it is supposed to reference the integer `Id` column in `Materials`.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO Suppliers(Id,CompanyId,MaterialId) VALUES (NEWID(), (SELECT distict Id FROM Companies WHERE Name = 'Wickes'),(SELECT distict Id FROM Materials WHERE Name = 'Bricks'));

Answer (score 0):

If I understand rightly Companies are the suppliers and the Suppliers table is the one that says where you can buy each material from.

Why do you have duplicates? Do you have an account for different branches of Wickes for example? If they are really duplicates and you don't care which one you use a function like `MIN()` will do the job of ensuring that only one value is returned. If you have duplicates it would be a good idea to find a way of disactivating all except one. This will make is simpler for you everytime you want to deal with the supplier: minimum orders, chasing overdue orders, payments etc.

Also Companies.ID and Materials.ID should be foreign keys of the Suppliers table. It is also a good idea for the ID column to be auto-incrementing, which makes it easier to add new products as you do not need to specify the ID column.
If you cannot or do not want to modify the id column to auto-incrementing `IDENTITY` you can continue to use `NEWID()`.

> ```
> create table Companies(
> id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
> name VARCHAR(25));
> create table Materials(
> id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
> name VARCHAR(25));
> create table Suppliers(
> id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
> CompanyId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Companies(id),
> MaterialId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Materials(id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Companies (name) VALUES ('Wickes');
> INSERT INTO Materials (name) VALUES ('Bricks');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Suppliers ( CompanyId, MaterialId) 
> SELECT  c.Id, M.Id
> FROM    Companies AS c
>         CROSS JOIN Materials AS m
> WHERE   c.Name = 'Wickes'
> AND     m.Name = 'Bricks';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Companies;
> SELECT * FROM Materials;
> SELECT * FROM Suppliers;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  
> -: | :-----
>  1 | Wickes
>
> id | name  
> -: | :-----
>  1 | Bricks
>
> id | CompanyId | MaterialId
> -: | --------: | ---------:
>  1 |         1 |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=418bfc8318db5a18a07f489bfdfd20f8)*

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO SUPPLIERS
(ID, COMPANYID, MATERIALID)
VALUES  (NEWID(),
(SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM COMPANIES WHERE NAME = 'Wickes'),   (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM MATERIALS WHERE NAME = 'Bricks'))

Comment: Instead of posting a new answer you can edit your original answer to add the changes you want to make.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).